# When Droppable removes some children that would be a wrong

Tags: jquery

This is my example : http://www.hyh.clhyc.tw/DropDrag.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".to_Grab" ).draggable({ 
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move'
    });
    var $length = 0;

    $(".drop").droppable({
        accept: ".to_Grab",
        drop: function( event, ui ) 
        {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone(true));
            $length = $(this).children(".to_Grab").length;
            if($length >= 2)
            {
                $(this).droppable( "disable" );
            }
        },
        disabled:false,
    }); 

    $(".delete").click(function(e){ 
        $(this).closest(".to_Grab").remove();
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(".drop").droppable( "enable" );       //problem
    });
});
```

---

Problem : 
{to limit DropBox_1 & DropBox_2 just only two elements}

if DropBox_1 and DropBox_2 got full
 then I delete one of element from DropBox_1, 
 then I drag an element from DragBox to DropBox_2, It would exceed the limit.

How to figure out the wrong_?

Comment: I don't understand what it is your asking... You can only drop 2 items into each dropbox. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry. 
That can only drop 2 items into each dropbox. This is Right.
But if I do above action, that would be Wrong. <because exceed my limit(2)> This is my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you are deleting don't enable every .drop, just the one you want:

```
$(".delete").click(function(e){ 
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.closest(".drop").droppable( "enable" );
      $this.closest(".to_Grab").remove();
      e.preventDefault(); 
  });
```